# Autoplay otro video cuando termine el original

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como puedo hacer para que cuando termine de reproducirse el video por completo se ejecute otro diferente en modo autoplay.
Algo asi como en Youtube cuando terminas un video y te dejan unos segundos hasta que ejecutan otro automaticamente.

```
<video autoplay muted preload="none"
src="vid/video001.mp4"
style=" position:absolute; width: 100vw;
-webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
from(rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)))">
</video>
```

Cuando acabe el video001 quiero que se ejecute el "video002" con el mismo gradiente y en autoplay...
Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1):

Has probado con javascript mediante un Evento ended ?
con el metodo setAttribute puedes cambiar el artributo src y cambiar el video al que tu desees, sin cambiar los demas atributos. Te deje una plantilla similar, disculpa si no me hago entender, soy un aprendiz aun.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Video</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  function iniciar() {
   video=document.getElementById('video');
   video.addEventListener('ended',reproducir,false);
     }

  function reproducir() {
         video.setAttribute('src', 'musica2.mp4');
  }
  window.addEventListener('load',iniciar,false);
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <video id="video" autoplay muted
        controls src="musica.mp4">
        </video>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```